# Basic Probability Question - n pairs of shoes in a closet

Tags: probability

A closet contains $n$ pairs of shoes, so there are a total of $2n$ shoes.

a) Each pair of shoes has its own corresponding box. If $n = 4$, what is the probability that at least one pair of shoes is placed in the correct box?

b) If $2r$ shoes are chosen at random from the closet with $2r$ $\leq$ $n$, what is the probability that there will be **exactly one** matching pair in the selection?

I have tried thinking about this problem on my own and I think the answer of a) is $ 1 - (\frac{3}{4})^4 = \frac{175}{256}$ .

For b) I have not gotten much further than deducing that there are $2n \choose 2r$ different ways in choosing shoes. Can someone explain the solution to me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your answer to part a) is incorrect, because the events are not independent.  This is about [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: You could use inclusion/exclusion for (a) with events $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ and computing $P[A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4]$.